# why is it possible to create String.java?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

Just trying to understand why I am able to create `String.java` file and it is compiled without any errors. As far as I know, the classloader chain will go to Bootstrap classloader and it has already loaded Sting.class.
Could you pls help me in understanding?

Comment: You probably haven't created it in the java.lang package .

Comment: Is it even conflicting the built-in class? The "original" `String` is `java.lang.String`.

Comment: you think that is bad? I once worked on a project where they created their own Object and String class ...

Comment: The classloader chain is entirely irrelevant when you compile *source code*. There is no such thing as class loaders at source code level. While you didn’t actually create source code for `java.lang.String`, it would be possible to do so. In the end, the Java authors had to do exactly that, to create the standard string class you’re using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class is not identified by just its name, but by its fully-qualified name, which is the name of the package followed by the name of the class.

If you create your own `String` class in some package `com.myapp`, then its fully-qualified name will be `com.myapp.String`. It doesn't conflict with the standard `String` class, which has the fully-qualified name `java.lang.String`.

Of course, it's going to be very confusing when you do this, especially because classes in the package `java.lang` are imported by default. Therefore, in practice you should never write your own class `String`, or name any of your own classes the same as classes from the standard library (especially standard classes from the package `java.lang`).

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by Jesper, the uniqueness of a class is determined by its fully qualified name i.e., package..

Try importing both the String classes in another class, and you will observe the difference when you will try to use it.

```
import java.lang.String;
import com.myclass.String;
```

Now, for resolving the ambiguity, you need to refer a class by its fully qualified name.